# Is redis using cache?

Tags: redis

I restarted my redis server after 120 days.

Before restart, memory usage 29.5GB

After restarted, memory usage 27.5GB

So, how 2GB reduced comes?

Free memory in ram like this article https://redis.io/topics/memory-optimization

> Redis will not always free up (return) memory to the OS when keys are
>   removed. This is not something special about Redis, but it is how most
>   malloc() implementations work. For example if you fill an instance
>   with 5GB worth of data, and then remove the equivalent of 2GB of data,
>   the Resident Set Size (also known as the RSS, which is the number of
>   memory pages consumed by the process) will probably still be around
>   5GB, even if Redis will claim that the user memory is around 3GB. This
>   happens because the underlying allocator can't easily release the
>   memory. For example often most of the removed keys were allocated in
>   the same pages as the other keys that still exist. The previous point
>   means that you need to provision memory based on your peak memory
>   usage. If your workload from time to time requires 10GB, even if most
>   of the times 5GB could do, you need to provision for 10GB.
>
> However allocators are smart and are able to reuse free chunks of
>   memory, so after you freed 2GB of your 5GB data set, when you start
>   adding more keys again, you'll see the RSS (Resident Set Size) to stay
>   steady and don't grow more, as you add up to 2GB of additional keys.
>   The allocator is basically trying to reuse the 2GB of memory
>   previously (logically) freed.
>
> Because of all this, the fragmentation ratio is not reliable when you
>   had a memory usage that at peak is much larger than the currently used
>   memory. The fragmentation is calculated as the amount of memory
>   currently in use (as the sum of all the allocations performed by
>   Redis) divided by the physical memory actually used (the RSS value).
>   Because the RSS reflects the peak memory, when the (virtually) used
>   memory is low since a lot of keys / values were freed, but the RSS is
>   high, the ratio mem_used / RSS will be very high.

Or free memory of caches which was used by my redis server?

Is redis using cache? Cache of cache?

Thanks!

Comment: I suggest you wait for several days and look again. Although there are a lot (too lot) reasons why process don't release memory to OS. It could be memory fragmentation but also it could be "as intended": database- and database-like services are typicaly designed so that they almost never release once aquired memory. And for a good reason: it expected that this memory will be needed in future - so it makes no sense to release it.